# Change Data Capture in Pentaho 8.3 Version Start_Date Issue for the Second execution

Tags: mysql, oracle, teradata, pentaho

I have completed the First Run for the Change Data Capture from Source(Oracle) to Target(MySQl) through pentaho 8.3 Community edition successfully with (START_DATE : 1900-01-01 03:00:00), 
(END_DATE : 2019-10-22 10:14:11) in the Log Table of the Pentaho(Transformation Properties >> Logging >> Transformation), But when I execute the same job, the **START_DATE is 2019-10-22 19:14:11** instead of 
2019-10-22 10:14:11(Which is previous END_DATE) here the 9hours are added to the second START_DATE.

Can someone please help..

Comment: It should not happen, did you made any change in your default configuration of step?

Comment: I did not make any changes to the default configurations, all the Date fields have DATETIME datatype.

Comment: Issue is resolved.. as it was referring to the DATETIME of the server which is on cloud, changed the TIMEZONE of the server to the LOCAL Timezone..